# Establish that the power function of the test is equal to ....

Tags: probability, statistics

Establish that the power function of $\delta_{c}(x_1, \cdots, x_n)=I\{X_{(n)}\geq c\}$, that is

$\pi_{c}(\theta)=P(\delta_{c}(x_1, \cdots, x_n)=1 | \theta)$ is equal to

$\pi_{c}(\theta)= 1-(\frac{c}{\theta})^n$ if $c\leq \theta$ or $0$ if $c>0$

I have,

$\pi_{c}(\theta)=P(reject H_o | \theta)=P(X_{(n)} \geq c | \theta)=P(max\{x_1, \cdots, x_n\} \geq c |\theta)$

$= 1-P(max\{x_1, \cdots, x_n\} \leq c |\theta)=1-[P(X_i \leq c)]^n$

After this I'm trying to figure out how $[P(X_i \leq c)]^n$ becomes $(\frac{c}{n})^n$

Comment: Which distribution does the $X_i$s follow?